# What are the differences between the “Home Edition” and the regular Mathematica?

Tags: home-edition

The [product page](http://store.wolfram.com/view/app/homeedition/) for *Mathematica Home Edition* says:

> Mathematica Home Edition is intended for hobbyists and enthusiasts alike, for non-professional use. If you wish to integrate Mathematica in your work, teaching, or research, other licensing options are available.

but I cannot find there [nor here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica-home-edition/) any technical description of the differences. Are those two different products? Or is it the same software sold under two names corresponding to two different licensing restrictions?

Comment: I spent time looking for this as well the other day and couldn't find anything except for this disclaimer: "Mathematica Home Edition is not licensed for commercial, nonprofit, academic, or government use and is available in the U.S., Canada, the U.K., Europe, and Japan."

Comment: While I have no authoritative answer, I have the home edition on my laptop (and use the "normal" edition on my office machine). As far as I can tell, there are no differences, apart from a banner (that you can trivially remove). I remember something about the Home Edition kernel being 32-bit only but I see my kernel is 64-bit. I am not aware of any other differences.

Comment: @acl All those `?Developer`*` and `?Compile`*` utilities are there ?

Comment: @Artes yes, as far as I can tell, nothing is missing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/how-to-buy/hobbyist.html):

> *Q: How is Mathematica Home Edition different from the professional version of Mathematica?*
>
> Mathematica Home Edition includes all of the functionality found in the professional version. The difference is that Mathematica Home Edition is only authorized for use on personally owned computers for non-professional and non-academic purposes.

Comment: Well, that’s what I was looking for, but I never managed to get to that particular page in the maze that is Wolfram’s website… Thanks!

Comment: @F'x, glad I could help.

Comment: I thought there was a difference in the number of parallel kernels they each can open, as well.

Comment: And I thought the home edition was 32 bit only

Comment: @P.Fonseca I'm using a home edition and it's 64-bit according to `SystemInformation[]`

Comment: I thought so too P.Fonseca. That's what people at Wolfram told me just a couple of months ago, but I trust @Heike more

Comment: Wasn't there a limit to the number of calls with WolframAlpha? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3406/57

Comment: My home edition has 4 kernels, which I think is standard.

Comment: This is false. Home eEdition has a huge banner at the top of every window that it's a pain to get rid of.