# Is it possible to use WolframAlpha servers to evaluate equations in Mathematica v8.0.4?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

Is it possible to use WolframAlpha computational power to evaluate equations in Mathematica version 8.0.4?

The thing is, it takes ages for my computer to evaluate certain equations. It would be great if I could use WolframAlpha (or something else?) to compute these equations .

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WolframAlpha.html ...but probably you will not get WRI to do very expensive calculations on their servers for you (for free at any rate).

Comment: And, perhaps, this will soon be of interest: http://online.wolfram.com/

Answer (score 4):

[image]

For limitations on many times you can use W/Aplha please see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/roughly-how-many-times-per-day-may-wolframalpha-be-used)

Answer (score 2):

The `WolframAlpha` function gives to access to Wolfram|Alpha in *Mathematica*.  Just like the Wolfram|Alpha web interface, there is a time limit on calculations.  Also, you can't run arbitrary *Mathematica* programs.  You need to use the "standard" W|A inputs.

While you can extend the time limit by subscribing to [W|A Pro](http://www.wolframalpha.com/pro/), I think what you are looking for is cloud computing services that support Mathematica.  Here's something I managed to google up:

http://www.wolfram.com/news/cloudcomputing.html

If you're in academia, you should inquire about the computational resources your university provides.

Comment: https://www.nimbisservices.com/shop/product/mathematica-on-amazon-custom-evaluation-package/ Cheaper to just get a few more computers, or maybe to set Mathematica up on EC2 yourself

Comment: @ssch Wow, that's expensive!