# Check remaining Wolfram|Alpha calls

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

As Wolfram|Alpha calls are [limited](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/roughly-how-many-times-per-day-may-wolframalpha-be-used/), and on the other side [increasingly frequent](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/293403?sortMsg=Flat), I'd like to be able to check how many calls am I able to make at a given time. Is there a function or system variable that keeps this information? Bonus points if it does not include making a call to W|A.

Comment: Please have a look [at my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56041/7167). It looks as if the current plan from Wolfram is to not charge for knowledge-based calls made from within Mathematica (Desktop versions).

Answer (score 8):

In Mathematica 10, this tells you the number of calls remaining in your cloud account if you are logged in:

```
CloudAccountData["WolframAlphaCallsAvailable"]
```

> 2168

Comment: This unfortunately does not work on the Raspberry Pi version of Mathematica 10. Is there a more general solution?

Comment: Oh it seems that you don't need to be logged in to the cloud to call Wolfram|Alpha as I thought. There are still a number of calls per day based on your MMA product key. I don't know how to obtain that information :/