# Known restrictions for WolframAlpha in CDF Player and PlayerPro

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, wolfram-player

Are there any known (documented?) restrictions for the use of the WolframAlpha function in CDF-Player and PlayerPro?

I only found [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3406/169) which mentions upper values for various license version, but it doesn't explicitly mention the two player variants and seem to be outdated (the link in it doesn't point to what it once did, I think).

Background: When I try a call to WolframAlpha in PlayerPro it just hangs with no message, even with the TimeConstraint option set to a low value. At least the TimeConstrained wrapper does work as it should. Of course I tested that the exact same code works without problems in Mathematica on the same machine. So I suspect that there are such restrictions but find it hard to find out what these are...